# delete leap days in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame in pandas like this:

```
    ID          Date        Element Data_Value
0   USW00094889 2014-11-12  TMAX    22
1   USC00208972 2009-04-29  TMIN    56
2   USC00200032 2008-05-26  TMAX    278
3   USC00205563 2005-11-11  TMAX    139
4   USC00200230 2014-02-27  TMAX    -106
```

I want to remove all leap days and my code is

```
df = df[~((df.Date.month == 2) & (df.Date.day == 29))]
```

but the AttributeError happened :

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'month'
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `dt` accessor:

```
df = df[~((df.Date.dt.month == 2) & (df.Date.dt.day == 29))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `dt` accessor because working with `Series`, not with `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df = df[~((df.Date.dt.month == 2) & (df.Date.dt.day == 29))]
```

Or invert condition with chaining `|` for bitwise `OR` and `!=` for not equal:

```
df = df[(df.Date.dt.month != 2) | (df.Date.dt.day != 29)]
```

Or use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for convert to `MM-DD` format:

```
df = df[df.Date.dt.strftime('%m-%m') != '02-29']
```

Comment: First one is mine :-)

Comment: @U9-Forward - Yes, some problem?

Comment: Na... no problem :D

Answer (score 2):

Another way you can try below in incase your `Date` column is not proper `datetime` rather a str.

```
df[~df.Date.str.endswith('02-29')]
```

OR , if it's in `datetime` format even you can try converting to `str`.

```
df[~df.Date.astype(str).str.endswith('02-29')]
```

OR, Even use contains:

```
df[~df.Date.str.contains('02-29')]
```